# What is the difference between pam_faillock and pam_tally2?

Tags: security, login, pam

To block a user after a preset number of failed login attempts, one would use a module like `pam_tally2` or `pam_faillock`.

What is the difference between these two? Which one should I use when?

Comment: Based on both modules manpage ([pam_faillock](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_faillock) and [pam_tally2](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_tally2)), it looks like pam_tally2 is a bit more evolved than pam_faillock, and comes with a userland program, `pam_tally2`, which allow you to manipulate counters (and so, speed up, or cancel a lock).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since Linux-PAM 1.4.0 (8th June, 2020) pam_tally and pam_tally2 were deprecated and pam_faillock was introduced, version 1.5.0 (10th November, 2020) removed pam_tally and pam_tally2

If your distro provides pam_faillock use that one, if not use pam_tally2

Source: https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/tags

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `pam_faillock` is the more evolved version, at least this was the case in 2016, when the author stated:

> Comment (by tmraz):
>
> I already submitted pam_faillock a few years ago. I agree with you that it should be included into Linux PAM and I really prefer not merging the code with pam_tally[2] as the internal design is quite different. I'd prefer to obsolete pam_tally and pam_tally2 altogether as their design is flawed.

Source: https://lists.fedorahosted.org/archives/list/pam-developers@lists.fedorahosted.org/thread/QIYGRKVWDHZUBQHOXZT67YJMCOEBDMHK/

Among the differences is that `pam_faillock` has improved handling of screensaver.